# Updating route in CamelContext for all instances in the cluster

Tags: apache-camel, cluster-computing

I have an application in which Camel routes can be added/removed dynamically during runtime. The problem appears when this app is deployed in a cluster(several pods in K8) and more than one instance is running. As each of the deployed apps has it's own CamelContext and K8 Service abstraction stands in front of them, the request for creating/deleting of a route reaches only one node. Hence CamelContext differs across applications and if next time request hits the other instance this results in an error.

What are the possible solutions to how routes/CamelContext can be synchronized in such case?

Comment: I think you need a publish/subscribe mechanism for administrative events. I'm not sure what pure kubernetes has in this area. Upcoming knative has its eventing facilities but is still alpha. You could still use a traditional message broker supporting publish/subscribe and use a topic to send a message to all subscribers (your Camel applications) triggering the required modifications.

Comment: by using the VM component https://camel.apache.org/vm.html so the context is shared in the same virtual machine OR use the JMX endpoint (I guess, http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html) OR as Sebastian suggested build your own solution